# Как сделать, чтобы каждый пользователь видел только те записи, которые он создал

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security, spring-data

Телефонная книга для каждого пользователя.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы у каждого пользователя имелась своя телефонная книга,  т.е. каждый пользователь видел только те записи, которые он создал.

Каким способом это лучше всего реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Если связать сущьность пользователя и телефонная книга отношением, то можно делать выборки телефонной книги пользователя, чтобы у каждого пользователя имелась своя телефонная книга т.е. каждый пользователь видел только те записи, которые он создал.

Можно конечно использоавть какой-нибудь фреймворк типа [`Spring Security`](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) или [`Apache Shiro`](https://shiro.apache.org/), но это будет очень громоздко для такой простой задачи как телефонная книга пользователя.

Comment: То есть я могу сделать что-то на подобии того, что я сделал с сущностями "Роль" и "Пользователь"?
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
 private List<Role> roles;

Comment: Нет у вас такой сущьности "Роль".

Comment: А можете показать как бы выглядел пример связи между пользователем и телефонной книгой посредством JPA аннотаций? Так же думаю выборку делать через JpaSpecificationExecutor или можно еще проще сделать?

Comment: JPA аннотации не самый лучший способ построения схем.